# Extract code from all available Git repositories

Tags: git, bash, powershell, bitbucket

For a specific reason I need to fetch all DTSX (SSIS package) stored in all git repositories (master branch). There are hundreds of repositories per project, and manual work seems daunting.

Is there a easy way, any UI, Git Bash, PowerShell code? that can look through all available repositories and download/extract DTSX file types to my machine?

Comment: Are those repos stored in one BitBucket organization?

Comment: Yes these are stored in same organisation. It is stash server hosted on primes at work.